# How to take Average of Duration in Hour & Minute in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, sqlplus

I need to take average of one of the column in table. it has duration in format of Hrs and Mins.

**Query**

```
select DURATIONHM from TableT where nownum < 9.
```

**Output**

```
DURATIONHM
--------------------------------
5 hrs 5 min
2 hrs 20 min
1 hrs 29 min
1 hrs 45 min
4 hrs 10 min
3 hrs 35 min
1 min
32 min
1 hrs 16 min

9 rows selected.
```

**Required Output.**

I need to take average `DURATIONHM`

```
select avg(DURATIONHM) as DurationTime from TableT
```

**Error**

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Output I need in also `Hour & Minute.`

Comment: Well... you'll have to parse the input data, then turn it all into minutes, then take the average and finally format the number into the original format back again. Awful work and query. You should consider saving data properly next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that bad if you use **regexp_substr**:

```
CREATE TABLE tablet (durationhm VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('5 hrs 5 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('2 hrs 20 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('1 hrs 29 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('1 hrs 45 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('4 hrs 10 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('3 hrs 35 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('1 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('32 min');
INSERT INTO tablet VALUES ('1 hrs 16 min');

COMMIT;

SELECT (NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) hrs', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0) * 60
        + NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) min', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0)) AS number_of_minutes
  FROM tablet;

NUMBER_OF_MINUTES      
---------------------- 
305                    
140                    
89                     
105                    
250                    
215                    
1                      
32                     
76                

SELECT AVG(NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) hrs', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0) * 60
        + NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) min', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0)) AS average_time
  FROM tablet;

AVERAGE_TIME           
---------------------- 
134,777777777777777777777777777777777778
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad58c/1

**Edit**: sorry, didn't see you also would like to get the answer in the format #of_hours hrs #of_minutes min. It gets ugly, but works (not sure at the moment how to write a query that will look better):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN average_time >= 60 THEN trunc(average_time / 60) || ' hrs'
                                    || 
                                      CASE
                                        WHEN MOD(average_time, 60) = 0 THEN NULL
                                        ELSE ' ' || MOD(average_time, 60) || ' min'
                                      END
      ELSE MOD(average_time, 60) || ' min'
    END AS average_formatted
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC(AVG(NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) hrs', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0) * 60
          + NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) min', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0))) AS average_time
      FROM tablet
);
```

Well, came up with another possibility (as ugly, though):

```
SELECT
 RTRIM(DECODE(TRUNC(average_time / 60), 0, NULL, trunc(average_time / 60) || ' hrs ') ||
    DECODE(MOD(average_time, 60), 0, NULL, MOD(average_time, 60) || ' min'))
      AS average_formatted
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC(AVG(NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) hrs', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0) * 60
          + NVL(regexp_substr(durationhm, '([0-9]+) min', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 0))) AS average_time
      FROM tablet
);
```

Comment: First thanks for your help and second I need the final `average_time` in `Hours & Minutes`, how can I get that?

Comment: I have added one more query, it is ugly, but you can work on improving it if you like. Don't have another idea for now how to make it look better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know this is very complicated, I finally gave up and posted the question here. THanks again for your help :)

Comment: [Two more ways to get the time](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad58c/3) if you're collecting them; though the first would need further manipulation...